# Sequenced video playback (cutlists) in Java.. can it be done?

Tags: java, video, media, sequence

If I have a bunch of video files, all in precisely the same format, shape, whatever, then can I play them back seamlessly without jumps or gaps? The effect from the end user's point of view would be as though they are watching one video.

I understand that this is possible in DirectX, but I'd rather use Java if possible.

Comment: Which format are those files? (AVI, MOV, MPEG, MKV, WM?) which Playload?   What are you using for Java playback, JMF? Can you have a sever side that will combine the file into a single stream?

Comment: AVI, most probably though if other formats make this easier then it may well be considered. There is no server component to the project. JMF is being considered but not essential.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play media in Java, the Sun standard is JMF (http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/) which unfortunately has been dormant for quite a while.

The FMJ project (http://fmj-sf.net/) is API-compatible and under active development.

I cannot answer your question better, but hopefully this can get you further.